# How to recover unsaved modifications of a saved Microsoft word file, version 15.30 using a MacBook Pro 2017?

Tags: microsoft-word

I saved my word document, quit out of the document. When i went to reopen it i discovered my document hadn't saved and the date that was last modified was the previous day. It did not only not save, it didn't even register that I was on the document. Please help! I am so stressed and hours of work was put into the document xxx

Comment: Office 2017 does not exist.  So what version are you actually running?  If the document did not automatically save, or you closed word without saving your document, there isn't file to recover.

Comment: i did save the document, then quit out of word.

Comment: it was version 15.30

Comment: What version of Office do you have installed?  I would assume it's Office 2016.  Edit your question, please do not reply with a comment, all relevant information should be within the body of the question.

Comment: As Ramhound mentioned already, if the document was not saved and you don't have autosave enabled then unfortunately you can not recover it. As you remember saving it, is it possible you've saved it with another name?

Comment: auto save is enabled for every 10 minutes. That is why i am confused as to why it did not save. And i have checked and it had not been saved under another name

Comment: This sounds like it may be a hiccup.  Things didn't happen the way they were supposed to happen or the way you thought they happened.  You can experiment with a dummy document to verify that it is working now the way it is supposed to.  But whatever happened to your previous document, there's no way to recover that.  Try to recreate it while it is still fresh in your mind.  Unfortunately, there isn't much anyone here can do to help in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you never saved the file, in other words the last name it had was Document#, you are never going to get it back. AutoRecovery does have a feature that saves the last "unsaved" version if you quit Word before initiating a Save ... but to work, the file must have been saved once and given a proper name.

With that said, I don't know if you even have that AutoRecovery feature because you version 15.30 of Mac Office, which is Office 2016, is over 2 years old. If you have a retail version (non-subscription version) you should be running 16.16.3.

If you had saved the file at some point and if you have Time Machine enabled, you could go back to the last saved version of the file by using Time Machine. Another option is if you had the preference set to Always Created a Backup, you could go to that last saved version of the file.

If your Mac Office version was updated to a subscription version, you would then truly have an AutoSave option to cloud storage ... otherwise you are confusing AutoSave with the AutoRecovery feature that I mentioned above.